# Error restarting FreeRADIUS service / "${dialect}" not found

Tags: mariadb, debian, freeradius, radius

everyone.

I'm trying to configure Radius on Debian 12 to control access to some Extreme Networks switches. I'm new to the operating system and Radius.
First, I created the database as follows.

`CREATE DATABASE radius; GRANT ALL ON radius.* TO 'radius'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; EXIT;`

Afterwards, I modified the following file "/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-available/sql" to add the following parameters:

`driver = "rlm_sql_mariadb"    database = "mysql"    server = "localhost"    port = 3306    login = "radius"    password = "password"    radius_db = "radius"`

Next, I proceeded to modify the file "/etc/freeradius/3.0/clients.conf" to add the switches.

`client switch1 {     ipaddr = 192.168.1.10       secret = mysecret            require_message_authenticator = no     nas_type = other     shortname = switch1     }`

And finally, I edited the file "/etc/freeradius/3.0/users" to be able to add the users.

`alan {     Cleartext-Password := "password123"     Reply-Message = "Welcome, alan!" }`

When trying to restart the Radius service, I encounter the following error:

[error al reiniciar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJKXD.png)

[sudo freeradius -cx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjMnD.png)

[systemctl status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqiFX.png)

[journalctl -xeu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dbV5.png)

I hope it's clear what the issue is. I hope you can help me with this, and I apologize for my limited knowledge in this area. Feel free to ask any questions.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

`raddb/mods-available/sql` has:

```
        dialect = "sqlite"
...
        driver = "rlm_sql_null"
#       driver = "rlm_sql_${dialect}"
```

You should change the `dialect` line from `sqlite` to `mysql`, not delete it. Then comment out the `rlm_sql_null` driver line and uncomment the one with `${dialect}` in it. Other parts of the configuration use the `${dialect}` option, so if you've removed it then you will see the error you are getting. Like this:

```
        dialect = "mysql"
...
#       driver = "rlm_sql_null"
        driver = "rlm_sql_${dialect}"
```

Note that the FreeRADIUS driver is `mysql`, not `mariadb`, so `rlm_sql_mariadb` will not work. The driver works for both.

You should also fix the formatting you are using in the `users` file - it does not have any `{` curly brackets `}`. See the example file for what format to use.

Finally, don't set `require_message_authenticator = no` for new clients. It's less secure, and only in the localhost example. Modern devices should all work with `yes`, and those that don't need to be replaced.